# Prove that if $p$ is prime and $p\mid a_1 a_2\cdots a_n$ then $ p| a_i$ for some $ i = 1, 2, ...., n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, induction, divisibility

Question:

Prove that if $p$ is prime and $p\mid a_{1} a_{2}\cdots a_{n}$ then $ p\mid  a_{i}$ for some $ i = 1, 2, ...., n$.

My attempt:

Proof by Induction:

Base Case: $n=1$, we have $ p\mid a_{1} \implies p\mid a_{1} $. So Base case holds.

I.H: Assume $ \ p\mid a_{1} a_{2}\cdots a_{k} \implies p\mid a_{i}\ $ for some  $\ i = 1, 2, ... k$

Consider $ n = k+1$

$ p\mid a_{1} a_{2}\cdots a_{k+1} \implies p\mid (a_{1} a_{2} \cdots a_{k})\, a_{k+1} \implies p\mid a_{1} a_{2}\cdots a_{k}\, $ or $ \ p\mid a_{k+1}$

If $\  p\mid a_{k+1}$ then we are done. Else by I.H $ \ p\mid a_{1} a_{2} \cdots  a_{k} \implies p\mid a_{i}\ $ for some $\ i = 1, 2, ... k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is fine. In fact we can similarly inductively extend any property $P$ that satisfies $\ P(ab) = P(a)\vee P(b)\,$ to products of any length, where $x \vee y := x\,$ or $\,y.\,$ Namely

$$\begin{align} P((a_1\cdots a_n) a_{n+1})\, &= \qquad\ \ \, P(a_1\cdots a_n)\vee P(a_{n+1})\\[.3em]
&=\, P(a_1)\vee \cdots P(a_n)\vee P(a_{n+1})\ \ {\rm by\ \ induction}
\end{align}$$

In your case $\,P(a) := p\mid a.\,$ Note that the only property used of multiplication and $\vee$ is associativity, so the proof is really about $n$-ary extension of monoid homomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

Now let me do it, considering you meant product. I will use $P$ to refer from here on to $a_1 a_2 ... a_n$. Note that $p|P$, so $P$ contains at least 1 factor of $p$. When you now partition $P$ as a product of some integers, $p$ must obviously show up somewhere in that product. Either one of the $a_i$ is therefore $p$, or one of the $a_i$ contains $p$ in its prime decomposition. If one $a_i$, say $i=x$ equals $p$, then clearly $a_x/p=p/p=1 \in \mathbb{Z} \implies p|a_x$, which satisfies what you originally wanted to prove (Q.E.D). Or you could have for a certain $a_i$, once again, say $i=x$, that contains a factor of $p$ in its prime decomposition. Therefore, $a_x=p b$, for some integer $b$. This means that $a_x/p=b \in \mathbb{Z} \implies p|a_x$ [Q.E.D.].

Comment: Induction is not needed, but if you wish to use it, I believe you are on the right track. Just try to make your proof use less assumptions, and even small lemmas that you used to aid your proof should be proved.

Answer (score 0):

We divide this into two main cases, either all $a_i$ are relatively prime, or they are non-relatively prime. First, for the relatively prime case, clearly $p=1$, and therefore $p$ must evenly divide all $a_i$. Now consider the second case. Let the GCD be $g$, where $g$ is not $1$. Now, for all $a_i$ let $a_i=gb_i$, where all $b_i$ are integral. We know $p$ divides $g$, so $p$ is a prime factor of $g$. Therefore, $g=\alpha p^\lambda$, for integers $\alpha,\lambda$, so for all $a_i$, $a_i=\alpha p^\lambda b_i$, and $a_i/p=\alpha p^{\lambda -1} b_i \in \mathbb{Z} \implies p|a_i$, for all $i$ [Q.E.D]

EDIT: This proof was done assuming you meant GCD. I will keep it on here for educational purposes anyway, though. I redid the proof using the fact that you meant product instead, so refer to that.

Comment: oops NVM I thought u meant GCD

Comment: I redid the proof assuming u meant product.

Comment: Looking at your own wording, "all... relatively prime" or "non-relatively prime" is ambiguous.  One might have all $a_i$ pairwise relatively prime (in which case the logical alternative is quite wieak, some pair is not coprime), or one might have "joint" coprimality (that GCD of all $a_i$ is $1$) and a correspondingly strong alternative (that GCD exceeds $1$).

Answer (score 0):

This step

$p\mid a_{1} a_{2}\cdots a_{k+1} \implies p\mid (a_{1} a_{2} \cdots a_{k})\, a_{k+1} \implies p\mid a_{1} a_{2}\cdots a_{k}\,$ or $\ p\mid a_{k+1}$.

assumes *precisely* what you want to prove:  That if $p\mid Ma$ then $p\mid M$ or $p \mid a$.

If you are going to assume this you must make your base case $k=2$ and not $k = 1$ else you will have an [all horses are the same color error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color).

Case $k=2$ is precisely [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)

If you know Bezout's Lemma we know that if $p|a_1a_2$ and $p\not \mid a_1$ then we know there are integers $m,n$ so that $pm + na_1 = 1$  Therefore $pma_2 + na_1a_2 = a_2$.  But $p|a_1a_2$ and $p|pma_2$ so $p|pma_2 + na_1a_2 = a_2$.  So either $p|a_1$ or if not, $p|a_2$.

*NOW* your induction step works just fine.