# Is this proof valid? $P|a^k \implies P|a$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction, divisibility

I'm trying to prove $P|a^k \implies P|a$

$p$ is a prime,
$a \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \\$,
$n \geq 2 \in \mathbb{Z}$

I know that: $P|ab \implies P|a \text{ or } P|b \dots [1]$

a is a positive integer,
b is a positive integer

**Base**:
 $P|a^2 \implies P|a$

$P|aa \implies P|a$ using [1]

**Induction hypothesis**:
 Assume $P|a^k \implies P|a$

**Check**: $P|a^{k+1} \implies P|a$

$P|aa^k \implies P|a$ using [1]

therefore $P|a^k \implies P|a$

Comment: Duplicate of [Prove that if $p$ is prime and $p\mid a_1 a_2\cdots a_n$ then $ p| a_i$ for some $ i = 1, 2, ...., n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376157/prove-that-if-p-is-prime-and-p-mid-a-1-a-2-cdots-a-n-then-p-a-i-for-some)

Comment: Bill Dubuque its not a duplicate. I use a different method and different base case

Comment: Au contraire, it is essentially the same (you should use that simpler base case, but the base case plays no role in the essence of your question).  A *good* answer would have explained that and much more (but it's unlikely you'll get one after accepting the fastest answer - a common newbie mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct. From $P\mid a^{k+1}=a\times a^k$, what you can deduce is that $P\mid a$ or that $P\mid a^k$. And *then* you can use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: So,P|aXa^k -> P|a or P|a^k then, P|a*a^k -> P|a or (P|a^k -> P|a) ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.